# SQL query : name columns by "columnname.field"

Tags: sql, left-join, multiple-columns

Hello I've written the following query :

```
SELECT *
FROM [woJob]
LEFT JOIN [woJobTask]
    ON [woJob].jobID=[woJobTask].jobID
```

The query it returns has duplication columns but they are named the same.  Is it possible to name column by table.Field.   For example, name woJob.jobID and woJobTask.jobID?

My work flow is to use SQL to get the data out of the database and then im using pandas (a python library) to explore the data.  Having duplicate column names makes things a little more complicated analyzing the data in python.  I want to get all the data out labeled up with column names so I know each column belongs to which table and then analyze the data in Pandas, I can drop any columns in pandas I don't want.

Comment: List the columns independently.  Use aliases to assign aliases if you want columns from both tables.

Comment: Is that the only way>?  I updated the query with my workflowto further explain.  My workflow my not be optimal but if you have any insight, that would be useful.  typing alias is long winded for a first analysis of the data.

Answer (score 1):

You need to enumerate the columns, and assign alias as needed.

You did not tell what the columns of the tables are, so here is a contrived example, assuming colums `jobid`, `name` and `value` in both tables:

```
SELECT j.jobid, j.name, j.value, jt.name as jt_name, jt.value as jt_value
FROM [woJob] j
LEFT JOIN [woJobTask] jt ON j.jobid = jt.jobid
```

Or more simply:

```
SELECT j.*, jt.name as jt_name, jt.value as jt_value
FROM [woJob] j
LEFT JOIN [woJobTask] jt ON j.jobid = jt.jobid
```